# AWS JAVA SDK V2 - how to work with metadata service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-java-2.0

till now i am working with V1 of the SDK, how ever I need to support IMDSV2. although in the V1 code I see it support it, actually it isnt, as I still getting 401 and it seems that I need to query the token and pass it to the metadata utils. I wanted to see if in V2 it was fixed, but i dont see in their doc, how to interact with the metadata service

Comment: Am having same issue. Springboot microservices are failing with 401 errors after switching to imdsv2. Looks like any calls to AWS Parameter Store is failing because java is not able to read instance profile of eks by querying imdsv2

Answer (score 1):

spring cloud 1.12 resolved the issue for me. This version supports IMDSv2 and not the older ones.